# Iodine clock reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I have been investigating the iodine-clock reaction for my chemistry project. I have done a great deal of research on the titration of iodate ions, iodide ions and sodium thiosulfate using HCl. But, I still don't get the use of this reaction. Where can this type of reaction be used in our lives.

I read articles that said iodine clock reaction can be used to determine the concentrations or pH. But where can it be used? What are the real-life applications of the iodine clock reaction?

Comment: I doubt if there's much interest in it besides academic research and popularization of chemistry.

Comment: You need to separate the iodine clock reaction (one that ticks back and forth) from the underlying iodine-forming reaction that leads to the starch-iodine complex. Only the latter has proper applications.

Comment: Yes, these reaction are only of academic interest only and do not find any practical purposes. These reaction are very special due to its unique kinetic and thermodynamic properties.

Comment: I believe these so-called "iodine clock reactions" are frequently used to teach chemical kinetics in the school laboratory?

Answer (score -1):

This iodine clock reaction project can apply to the real world in different ways, but I think the biggest way is concentration. After doing some research, I found out that it can teach you about concentration, because it shows you that once you add any bigger amount to a substance, it changes reaction time, or in a real world case, how a substance feels, acts, looks, and possibly how it smells.

I know this is really late and you probably don't need this and you are done your project, but I'm just a bored grade 7 doing the same science project.